# How to make my if statement output the correct printf C program

Tags: c, if-statement, compilation, generator

In the code below I have made a program that can make the amount of money you put in transfer into words. For example, "1234.56" turn into "One Thousand Two Hundred Thirty Four and ... 56 Cents". The thing is that when I try to input the amount "0.01" into my `scanf`, the output becomes "Dollars and ... 1 Cents" when it should output "Zero Dollars and ... 1 Cent". Please help!

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printNum(int);
void printNum2(int);

int main()
{

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0; 
    int num = 0;
    int printcents; //To convert the float "cents" to an integer.

    float inclusive;
    float cents;

    printf("Welcome to the IPC144 Cheque Generator!!\n");
    printf("PAY TO THE ORDER OF... amahmood29 (018359133)\n");
    printf("Enter a monetary value from $0.01 to $9999.99 inclusive: ");
    scanf("%f", &inclusive);

    if(inclusive < 0.00 || inclusive >= 10000.00) {
        printf("Sorry, cannot create cheque for that amount, try again next time!\n");
    }
    else
    {                                             
        a = inclusive / 1000;                          //This data is replacing our variable by diving whatever the vaulue is by either 1000, 100, 10.
        inclusive = inclusive - (a*1000);
        b = inclusive / 100; 
        inclusive = inclusive - (b*100);
        if ( inclusive > 19 ){
            c = inclusive / 10; 
            inclusive = inclusive - (c*10);
        }
        else
        {
            c = inclusive;
            d = 0;
        }
        d = inclusive;
        num = inclusive;
        cents = (inclusive - num)*100; //To calculate our "Cents" with numerals.
        printcents = cents;


        /*Printing if the variables are in the thousands, hundreds, tens or ones categories.*/
        if (a > 0){ 
            printNum(a);  
            printf("Thousand ");
        }
        if (b > 0){
            printNum(b);
            printf("Hundred ");
        }
        printNum2(c);   
        if (d >= 0){
            printNum(d);
            printf("Dollars and ... ");
        }
        else if (c == 0 && b == 0 && a == 0){
            printf("Zero Dollars and ... ");
        }
        printf("%d", printcents);
        printf(" Cents\n");
    }
}

void printNum(int x)  //Created functions to easily output various if statements.
{

    if ( x == 1)
        printf("One ");
    else if ( x == 2)
        printf("Two ");
    else if (x == 3)
        printf("Three ");
    else if (x == 4) 
        printf("Four ");
    else if (x == 5)
        printf("Five ");
    else if (x == 6)
        printf("Six ");
    else if (x == 7)
        printf("Seven ");
    else if (x == 8)
        printf("Eight ");
    else if (x == 9)
        printf("Nine ");

    }

void printNum2(int x)
{
    if ( x == 10)
        printf("Ten ");
    else if ( x == 11)
        printf("Eleven ");
    else  if ( x == 12)
        printf("Twelve ");
    else if ( x == 13)
        printf("Thirteen ");
    else if (x == 14)
        printf("Fourteen ");
    else if (x == 15)
        printf("Fifteen ");
    else if (x == 16)
        printf("Sixteen ");
    else if (x == 17)
        printf("Seventeen ");
    else if (x == 18)
        printf("Eighteen ");
    else if (x == 19)
        printf("Nineteen ");
    else if (x == 2)
        printf("Twenty ");
    else if (x == 3)
        printf("Thirty ");
    else if (x == 4)
        printf("Forty ");
    else if (x == 5)
        printf("Fifty ");
    else if (x == 6)
        printf("Sixty ");
    else if (x == 7)
        printf("Seventy ");
    else if (x == 8)
        printf("Eighty ");
    else if (x == 9)
        printf("Ninety ");
}
```

Comment: `printf("Dollars and ... ");` --> `printf("Zero Dollars and ... ");`?

Comment: `printNum(d)` when `d == 0` it becomes `printNum(0)`. Inside `void printNum(int)` you have all numbers covered except for `0`, hence it exits the function silently without printing anything. You should change the condition `if (d>0)` instead of `if (d>=0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested `if else`. First check if it is zero dollars, else carry out your process. Try something like this:

```
if (c == 0 && b == 0 && a == 0){
   printf("Zero Dollars and ... ");
}
else{
   if (a > 0){
      printNum(a);
      printf("Thousand ");
   }
   if (b > 0){
      printNum(b);
      printf("Hundred ");
   }
   printNum2(c);
   if (d >= 0){
      printNum(d);
      printf("Dollars and ... ");
   }
}
```

instead of

```
if (a > 0){ 
   printNum(a);  
   printf("Thousand ");
}
if (b > 0){
   printNum(b);
   printf("Hundred ");
}
printNum2(c);   
if (d >= 0){
   printNum(d);
   printf("Dollars and ... ");
}
else if (c == 0 && b == 0 && a == 0){
   printf("Zero Dollars and ... ");
```

as in your code the `if(d>=0)` satisfies, it would never enter the `else if` statement (`else if` skips if any previous statement is true).

Answer (score 0):

VERY quick look, but:

```
if (d > 0){
    .....
```

Again, this was a QUICK look and I didn't test it.

Comment: If I do that then It works if I input 0.01 as the output becomes "Zero Dollars and ... 1 cent" HOWEVER if I try to input only "1000" then the output becomes "One Thousand 0 Cents" when its supposed to say "One Thousand Dollars and ... 0 Cents". Any other possible suggestions, sir? I have been coding for a month so I'm sorry if you try to do this that the answer is obvious.